# problema con libreria en javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose

estoy con node usando la libreria de mongoose y cierta parte del codigo me aparece en un color verde claro y al iniciar el documento con node "nombre".js me da error,  ¿Es por que no conecté correctamente la librería?, disculpenme soy nuevo.

Comment: Pon la parte del código necesaria para reproducir el problema aclarando dónde te muestra el error y que mensaje te da, como texto y formateado como código con las herramientas del sitio.

Comment: En vez de escribir un título ambiguo, pon un título que resuma en pocas palabras el problema que estás teniendo. Lee [ask].

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.